# Retrieve Data from Table1 using Table2's foreign key and description field

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I can't explain it thoroughly in the title, but what I am trying to explain is: I have two tables a table for the assets and a table for the type of assets determined by the AssetCode. In the second table(AssetCode Table), there is the CodeID field, which is related to the AssetCode field in the first table (Assets Table), and the CodeDescription field which indicates the description of the code (e.g. laptop, chair, printer, etc.). Is it possible to retrieve the data of the first table using the second table's CodeDescription field?

Comment: yes you can do that: `SELECT * FROM assets s INNER JOIN assetType t ON s.assetCode = t.CodeId WHERE t.CodeDescription ='chair';`

Comment: Can you also please share your tables definition like columns and data types?

Comment: Table1 AssetCode INT
Table1 AssetName VARCHAR
Table2 CodeID INT
Table2 CodeDescription VARCHAR

Comment: And what are you expecting as output? Did you try my above code?

Comment: let me know if it works

Comment: You don't need to explain it thoroughly, you just need to provide sample data (DDL+DML) and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
SELECT 
    t1.*
FROM
    Table1 t1,
    Table2 t2
WHERE
    t1.AssetCode = t2.CodeID
        AND t2.CodeDescription = 'chair';
```

Comment: Glad it worked. You can accept it as an answer than.